# Css hovering link show table

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make a dropdown menu where when hovering a link. A table is shown underneath the link. I don't understand why it wont work. Check out the fiddle link.

*FIXED LINK*
http://jsfiddle.net/ThobiasN/Pt3db/

Html code example:

```
<a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='dropdown'><p>Show me</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Css code example:

```
td.dropdown
{
    display:none;
}

a.nav:hover > table
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I think you posted the wrong fiddle.

Comment: Huh? the fiddle is working just fine...

Comment: Oh yea, it is the wrong fiddle sorry. Il fix that for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3db/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at the end you would need to use some Javascript code to achieve that, but what you are doing wrong is this:

- `>` simbol is for direct child
- You want to set `display: none` for the `table` element, not the `td`

Solution:

- change the `>` symbold for this one: `+` to get the next element
- change a little bit your css

#### HTML

```
<a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='dropdown'><p>Show me</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table{
    display:none;
}

a.nav:hover + table{
    display:block;
}
```

#### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3db/5/

#### Plus advices

- Use an unordered list instead `table` (table for tabular data)
- You wouldn't be able to click on the subnav elements, so that's why I think you would need some Javascript
- Out there are a lot of good navigation plugins that you can use, don't reinvent the wheel at least you are learning ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because the table isn't a child of the link.
The sign `>` in CSS is equivalent to "direct child of"

Try to put the table inside of the link.

Comment: So I tried your solution. But it still dosnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/ThobiasN/Pt3db/1/

Comment: Yes, that was because you hid the table data field. The table itself is visible all the time. So you have two options. 1: Show the tr.dropdown when hovering the a-tag or 2: hide the complete table by default.

Answer (score 3):

`<table>` is a sibling to link element. Use + for operating over the sibling.

```
a.nav + table {
  display: none;

}
a.nav:hover + table {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to do it, **CSS**:

```
a.nav + table tr td.dropdown
{
display:none;
}

a.nav:hover + table tr td.dropdown
{
display:block;
}
```

You need to hide and show the same element, if you hide a table, don't show a TD, and vice versa

Alternatively, show and hide table instead of TD, **CSS**:

```
a.nav + table 
{
display:none;
}

a.nav:hover + table 
{
display:block;
}
```

One more thing to keep in mind, + refers to sibling elements, > refers to direct child

Comment: You could have just pasted the code snippet in here instead of giving us the links that are not clickable :(

Answer (score 2):

a.nav:hover > table means that table should be inside a.nav. First of all don't use table here, use ul better and put it inside a.nav

```
<a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me
  <ul>
    <li>Show me</li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with css [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3db/3/)

It seems to work either way but here is the way that I prefer
even though it's not css:

```
$('.nav').hover(function () {
    $('table').css('display', 'block');
});

table{    
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<a class='nav' href='#'>Hover me </a>
<table class='dropdown'>
    <tr>
        <td ><p>Show me</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code

```
table.dropdown
{
    display:none;
}
a.nav:hover + table
{
    display:block;
    color: green;
}
```